# PING - TTL changes from 64 to 128 and back

Tags: ping

I'm having an issue with an Ubuntu 18 LTS server where I cannot SSH to the server.

I'm connecting to a Ubuntu server via Putty SSH and have 1 router hop between my windows jump server and the Ubuntu server.

I have found that if I ping the Ubuntu server I receive the following message:

```
Reply from 10.10.10.10: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=63
```

During an extended ping the message will change to:

```
Reply from 10.10.10.10: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=127
```

When this happens I loose my SSH connection to the server and can not longer connect to it.
once the message goes back to:

```
Reply from 10.10.10.10: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=63
```

I can connect again.

I could not find anything on the Layer-3 device (Cisco switch) that would explain why this happened.

**Question**: Why would the TTL change?  Is there something in the Ubuntu OS that could be causing this issue?